# React JS component not updating on state change

Tags: json, reactjs

I've been trying to implement a method in which you can sort a leaderboard in different ways, by toggling a select element which changes the state, causing the component to re-render.

The problem is that, it can sort the default correctly, but whenever I change the value of the select from default to "z-to-a", it does not seem to be updating.

Note: I've added a few console.log statements, which seem to be behaving weirdly.

My JSX:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Leaderboard.css';
import LbRow from '../../components/LbRow/LbRow'; /* A row in the leaderboard*/
import points from '../../data/tree-points.json';

function Leaderboard() {
    // Initialize the points as the data that we passed in
    const [state, setState] = useState({
         points: points,
         sortBy: "first-to-last"
    });

    // Changes the sort method used by the leaderboard
    const changeSortBy = (event) => {
        var newSort = event.target.value;

        // Sorts the data differently depending on the select value
        switch(newSort) {
            case "first-to-last":
                sortDescending("points","first-to-last");
                break;
            case "z-to-a":
                sortDescending("tree_name","z-to-a");
                console.log(state.points.treePoints); // Logs incorrectly, still logs the same array as in "first-to-last"
                break;
            default:
                sortDescending("points","first-to-last");
        }

        // Re-renders the component with new state
        setState({
            points: state.points,
            sortBy: newSort
        });

    }

    /* Updates the leaderboard state to be in descending point order */
    const sortDescending = (aspect, sortMethod) => {

        console.log(sortMethod); // Logs correctly

        // Sorts the data in descending points order
        let sortedPoints = [...state.points.treePoints].sort((tree1, tree2) => {
            if (tree1[aspect] > tree2[aspect]) { return -1; }
            if (tree1[aspect] < tree2[aspect]) { return 1; }
            return 0;
        });

        // Actually updates the state
        setState({
            points: {
                ...state.points,
                treePoints: sortedPoints
            },
            sortBy: sortMethod
        });

        console.log(sortedPoints); // Logs correctly

    };

    /* Calls sortLb on component mount */
    useEffect(() =>{
            sortDescending("points", "first-to-last");
        } 
    ,[]);

    // Attributes used for rendering the leaderboard body
    var rank = 0;
    const sortedData = state.points;

    /* Basically all the active trees with the first tree having the top rank */
    const lbBody = sortedData.treePoints.map((sortedData) => {
        return (
            sortedData.active &&
            <LbRow rank={++rank} tree_name={sortedData.tree_name} points={sortedData.points} active={sortedData.active}/>
        );
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="filters">
                {/* Allows user to sort by different methods */}
                <label htmlFor="sortBy">Sort by:</label>
                <select name="sortBy" className="sortBy" value={state.sortBy} onChange={changeSortBy}>
                    <option value="first-to-last">First to Last</option>
                    <option value="z-to-a">Z to A</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            {/* The table with sorted content */}
            <div className="table">
                {lbBody}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Leaderboard;
```

I'm really confused by this behavior, especially since I have the correctly sorted value and supposedly already updated the state. What could be causing this to happen? THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 things you must note

- State updates are batched, ie. when you call setState multiple times within a function, their result is batched together and a re-render is triggered once
- State updates are bound by closures and would only reflect in the next re-render and not immediately after calling state updater
- State updates with hooks are not merged to you do need to keep merging all values in state yourself

Now since you wish to call the state updater twice, you might as well use the callback approach which will guarantee that your state values from multiple setState calls are not merged, since you don't need them to. Also you must update only the fields that you want to

```
function Leaderboard() {
  // Initialize the points as the data that we passed in
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    points: points,
    sortBy: "first-to-last"
  });

  // Changes the sort method used by the leaderboard
  const changeSortBy = (event) => {
    var newSort = event.target.value;

    // Sorts the data differently depending on the select value
    switch (newSort) {
      case "first-to-last":
        sortDescending("points", "first-to-last");
        break;
      case "z-to-a":
        sortDescending("tree_name", "z-to-a");
        break;
      default:
        sortDescending("points", "first-to-last");
    }

    // Re-renders the component with new state
    setState(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      sortBy: newSort // overrider just sortByField
    }));

  }

  /* Updates the leaderboard state to be in descending point order */
  const sortDescending = (aspect, sortMethod) => {

    console.log(sortMethod); // Logs correctly

    // Sorts the data in descending points order
    let sortedPoints = [...state.points.treePoints].sort((tree1, tree2) => {
      if (tree1[aspect] > tree2[aspect]) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (tree1[aspect] < tree2[aspect]) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });

    // Actually updates the state
    setState(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      points: {
        ...state.points,
        treePoints: sortedPoints
      },
    }));

  };

  /* Calls sortLb on component mount */
  useEffect(() => {
    sortDescending("points", "first-to-last");
  }, []);

  // Attributes used for rendering the leaderboard body
  var rank = 0;
  const sortedData = state.points;

  ...
}

export default Leaderboard;
```

Another better way to handle this to avoid complicated is to separate out your states into two useState

```js
function Leaderboard() {
    // Initialize the points as the data that we passed in
    const [points, setPoints] = useState(points);
    const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState(sortBy);

    // Changes the sort method used by the leaderboard
    const changeSortBy = (event) => {
        var newSort = event.target.value;

        // Sorts the data differently depending on the select value
        switch(newSort) {
            case "first-to-last":
                sortDescending("points","first-to-last");
                break;
            case "z-to-a":
                sortDescending("tree_name","z-to-a");
                console.log(state.points.treePoints); // Logs incorrectly, still logs the same array as in "first-to-last"
                break;
            default:
                sortDescending("points","first-to-last");
        }

        // Re-renders the component with new state
        setSortBy(newSort);

    }

    /* Updates the leaderboard state to be in descending point order */
    const sortDescending = (aspect, sortMethod) => {

        console.log(sortMethod); // Logs correctly

        // Sorts the data in descending points order
        let sortedPoints = [...state.points.treePoints].sort((tree1, tree2) => {
            if (tree1[aspect] > tree2[aspect]) { return -1; }
            if (tree1[aspect] < tree2[aspect]) { return 1; }
            return 0;
        });

        // Actually updates the state
        setPoints({
                ...state.points,
                treePoints: sortedPoints
        });

        console.log(sortedPoints); // Logs correctly

    };

    /* Calls sortLb on component mount */
    useEffect(() =>{
            sortDescending("points", "first-to-last");
        } 
    ,[]);

    // Attributes used for rendering the leaderboard body
    var rank = 0;
    const sortedData = points;

    /* Basically all the active trees with the first tree having the top rank */
    const lbBody = sortedData.treePoints.map((sortedData) => {
        return (
            sortedData.active &&
            <LbRow rank={++rank} tree_name={sortedData.tree_name} points={sortedData.points} active={sortedData.active}/>
        );
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="filters">
                {/* Allows user to sort by different methods */}
                <label htmlFor="sortBy">Sort by:</label>
                <select name="sortBy" className="sortBy" value={sortBy} onChange={changeSortBy}>
                    <option value="first-to-last">First to Last</option>
                    <option value="z-to-a">Z to A</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            {/* The table with sorted content */}
            <div className="table">
                {lbBody}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Leaderboard;
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, just as a note, deleting the setState at the end of changeSortBy ended up making it update as expected, too

Comment: Yeah that would work too since you were updating sortBy in sortDescending, but the other details are important for future uses :-)